# Wifi not working after upgrading from 12.04 to 13.10

Tags: 12.04, wireless, upgrade

I went through loads of posts looking for an answer to my WiFi problems but can't seem to fix it.

I had Ubuntu 12.04 installed and WiFi worked fine with no issues whatsoever but then I upgraded to 13.10 it has stopped working.

It shows the available networks but I can't connect to any of them it just does that animation thing then stops working.

Update

Heres the link to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/GyMMEYhv

And heres what wifi card i have and driver

`lspci`:

```
01:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:18de]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:18ec]
        Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
```

Comment: What kind of Wifi card do you have? Which driver are you using? **Please edit the question with these information.**

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.

Comment: user68186 and wild man i updated my post thanks for any help :)

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue and it became to work after this: go to Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers and turn off Wireless LAN Controller (select Do Not Use Device -> Apply)  and then turn on it again. During this process I was connected to internet via ethernet wire

Comment: i tried that, it only shows additional drivers for the graphics cards - think im going to have to install W8 then use ubuntu in a virtual box or something :(